# Better way to set dynamic names to items in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, token

Well, I have an item in localStorage named `products`. This item contains an `Array` of `JSON Objects` that contains products details like `quantity`, `unit_price`, etc...

Here is the trigger function to add products to table and update the table...

```
function addProduct() {
  try {
    //Add product to localstorage
    addProductToLocalStorage();
    //Update pre order table (products)
    updateTable();
    showAlert('Product added!', 'success', 'alert');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This item is assigned when the user wants to add products to an invoice, I use it to calculate subtotal, taxes and total cost values.

Here is where I add the product to `products` in localStorage

```
function addProductToLocalStorage() {
  try {
    //Temporary product
    let product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tempProduct"));
    let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
    //Check if the item already exists
    let products = item ? item : [];
    products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
    //Delete item
    localStorage.removeItem("tempProduct");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

`tempProduct` is an item that contains information about the product the user is adding, this is because I store information about the product from the server that is not printed to the user, is just to make calculations.

The item is cleared when the invoice is created.

```
function createInvoice(){
...
localStorage.removeItem("products");
}
```

The problem here is if the user wants to create two or more invoices and add products to the invoices at the same time, the item is going to store the data of both invoices and will make a mess with the values.

I'm thinking maybe setting dynamic names to the item, like a unique token for every 'Create Inovice' window opened will help me with this, but I don't know if there is a better solution. Let me know how would you deal with this.

Comment: can you post a code example of what you're running into? conceptually this is simple but without seeing your setup it's hard to say.

Comment: Your title is asking "How to" but your content is asking "is it good to".

Comment: I added more information about my setup @Phix

Comment: Just changed the title @RickyMo